# CKEditor edit data-* attributes

Tags: ckeditor

I need a solution that allows me to add/edit/remove `data-*` attributes on individual elements in CKEditor without manually adding it directly in the source editors?

I haven't found any config items or plugins that allow me to do this.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: If there are no existing plugins, you'll have to create your own one.

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a working sample based on the example you provided.](https://jsfiddle.net/chqt2eaw/)

You can add/edit/remove data attributes on elements with [this](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-data):

```
element.data( 'extra-info', 'test' );   // Appended the attribute data-extra-info="test" to the element.
alert( element.data( 'extra-info' ) );  // 'test'
element.data( 'extra-info', false );    // Remove the data-extra-info attribute from the element.
```

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-data

Comment: Your post interest me ! What is "element" ? How defines it ? for example, I have a " <span class='st' data-time-start='55'>blabla</span> " , How to get data-time-start of this span who have the class 'st' and finally get '55' ? thanks

Comment: element is your span. For me to help you with this I would need a sample of what you are doing so I know how you created your ckeditor control and how you inserted your elements. Use jsfiddle and create a sample.

Comment: thakns for your help ! I'm trying to do that : http://jsfiddle.net/zagloo/7hvrxw2c/8/

Comment: I updated my original answer with a new jsfiddle based on your sample

Comment: omg... Are You the CKEDITOR God ?? !! Nice to meet you !! It works perfectly !! thanks !

Comment: last question : how to remove class 'active' to all span and add class active to the $(this) span : http://jsfiddle.net/zagloo/7hvrxw2c/15/

Comment: you have a call to removeClass on spanelements when it should be spanelement * without the s

Comment: For anyone coming to this now, the link to load `ckeditor.js` was broken in jnoreiga's JSFiddle in their answer. Here's a version with it working: https://jsfiddle.net/chqt2eaw/